# How to merge coordinates into one value and return it?

Tags: c++

As above, any tricky methods to do so?
Since you cannot pass an array, I wonder how to return coordinates (x/column and y/row) to the calling object.
Regards.

Comment: How about a structure?

Comment: There is even a structure called array, to get you confused ;-)

Comment: You could even use an std::pair to leverage things already in the standard library

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of possibilities in c++ to do so, but I'm giving you a simple example:

```
 struct coords {
     int x;
     int y;
 };

 int calculate_value_of_x(int y);
 int calculate_value_of_y(int x);
 coords calc_coords() {
     coords c;
     c.x = calculate_value_of_x(c.y);
     c.y = calculate_value_of_y(c.x);
     return c;
 }
```